# Stripping off the seconds in datetime python

Tags: python

now() gives me

```
datetime.datetime(2010, 7, 6, 5, 27, 23, 662390)
```

How do I get just `datetime.datetime(2010, 7, 6, 5, 27, 0, 0)` (the datetime object) where everything after minutes is zero?

Answer (score 155, accepted):

```
dtwithoutseconds = dt.replace(second=0, microsecond=0)
```

http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace

Comment: Note that this is just a value and does not alter dt - if that's what you want then also assign it back to dt.

Comment: what if I don't actually want the seconds and microseconds at all, not just replace them with `0`s?

Answer (score 33):

I know it's quite old question, but I haven't found around any really complete answer so far.

There's no need to create a datetime object first and subsequently manipulate it.

`dt = datetime.now().replace(second=0, microsecond=0)`

will return the desired object

Answer (score 15):

You can use [`datetime.replace`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace) to obtain a new datetime object without the seconds and microseconds:

```
the_time = datetime.now()
the_time = the_time.replace(second=0, microsecond=0)
```

Comment: or `the_time= datetime.now().replace(second=0, microsecond=0)`

Answer (score 2):

Some said Python might be adding nanosecond anytime soon, if so the `replace(microsecond=0)` method mentioned in the other answers might break.

And thus, I am doing this

```
datetime.fromisoformat( datetime.now().isoformat(timespec='minutes') )
```

Maybe it's a little silly and expensive to go through string representation but it gives me a peace of mind.

Answer (score 1):

```
dt = datetime.datetime(2010, 7, 6, 5, 27, 23, 662390)
dt = f'{dt.date().__str__()} {dt.time().__str__()[:5]}'
```

Comment: This does not return a `datetime` object as asked. It's also not recommended to use an objects `__str__` function, e.g. `f'{str(dt.date())} {str(dt.time())[:5]}'`.